# Why _integrate_forces doesn't work get RigidBody2D has Gravity Scale set to 0?

Tags: godot

I am trying to drag and drop a RigidBody2D, however I have noticed that my code doesn't work at all if I set the Gravity Scale = 0 and if I set the Gravity Scale to 0.5 it works however if I drag it and stop moving the mouse for a second, it gets stuck in its place as if I did set the Gravity Scale to 0.

```
extends RigidBody2D

var is_held = false
func _ready():
    set_process_input(true)

func _integrate_forces(state):
    i = i + 1
    var lv = state.get_linear_velocity()

    if is_held:
        lv = (get_viewport().get_mouse_pos() - get_pos()) * 16

    state.set_linear_velocity(lv)

func _input(event):
    if event.type == InputEvent.MOUSE_BUTTON and not event.pressed and event.button_index == BUTTON_LEFT:
        is_held = false

func _on_food_input_event( viewport, event, shape_idx ):
    if event.type == InputEvent.MOUSE_BUTTON and event.pressed and event.button_index == BUTTON_LEFT:
        is_held = true
```

In the end what I am trying is to be able to drag and drop the rigid body either vertically or horizontally and not both nor diagonal.

Answer (score 1):

You must go in your visual editor under properties of the RigidBody2D and set the first property to "Mode:Character".
You function "_integrate_forces" is not called all the time in "Mode:Rigid". When it stops the engine stops to call it. But it is called all the time in "Mode:Character". That will solve your problem.